# only can select part of the image when using jcrop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, css

When using jcrop to crop the image uploaded, only a part of the picture can be selected, depicted as the picture below:
[image]

As show in the picture above, although the part of picture in the red rectangle can be selected, but it couldn't be cropped from the picture. What's wrong here?

My Html code:

```
<div class="span9">
    <div class="heading-banner">
        <h2 style="font-size:20px">我的头像</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label><span class="label">当前头像：</span></label>
        <img id="avatar" src="<?php echo base_url('/images/default.gif')?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label><span class="label">上传图片：</span></label>
        <input type="text" id="avatarUpload" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" id="img" name="img" />
        <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
        <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
        <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
        <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
        <div style="padding-top:-10px;">
            <a href="javascript:$('#avatarUpload').uploadify('upload','*')">开始上传</a> |
            <a href="javascript:$('#avatarUpload').uploadify('cancel', '*')">取消上传</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imgchoose">编辑头像：<br /><img src="" id="target" /></div>
    <div class="row imgchoose" style="display:none;">
        头像预览：<br />
        <div style="width:200px;height:200px;margin:10px 10px 10px 0;overflow:hidden; float:left;"><img class="preview" id="preview3" src="" /></div>
        <div style="width:130px;height:130px;margin:80px 0 10px;overflow:hidden; float:left;"><img class="preview" id="preview2" src="" /></div>
        <div style="width:112px;height:112px;margin:98px 0 10px 10px;overflow:hidden; float:left;"><img class="preview" id="preview" src="" /></div>
    </div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="button" class="btn_submit" value="" id="avatar_submit" style="display:none;" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="span3">
    <ul id="profile-list" class="nav nav-list">
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('user/basic')?>">我的个人资料</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('user/avatar');?>">修改头像</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    //首页轮播图1
    $("#avatarUpload").uploadify({
        'auto'              : false,
        'multi'             : false,
        'uploadLimit'       : 1,
        'formData'          : {'uid':'18'},
        'buttonText'        : '请选择图片',
        'height'            : 20,
        'width'             : 120,
        'removeCompleted'   : false,
        'swf'               : "<?php echo base_url('uploadify/uploadify.swf') ?>",
        'uploader'          : "<?php echo base_url('user/do_avatar');?>",
        'fileTypeExts'      : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png;',
        'fileSizeLimit'     : '1024KB',
        'debug':true,
        'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
            var msg = $.parseJSON(data);
            alert(msg.result_des);
            if( msg.result_code == 1 ){
                $("#img").val(msg.result_des );
                $("#target").attr("src",msg.result_des);
                $(".preview").attr("src",msg.result_des);
                $('#target').Jcrop({
                    minSize: [50,50],
                    setSelect: [0,0,200,200],
                    onChange: updatePreview,
                    onSelect: updatePreview,
                    onSelect: updateCoords,
                    aspectRatio: 1
                },
                function(){
                    // Use the API to get the real image size
                    var bounds = this.getBounds();
                    boundx = bounds[0];
                    boundy = bounds[1];
                    // Store the API in the jcrop_api variable
                    jcrop_api = this;
                });
                $(".imgchoose").show(1000);
                $("#target").show(1000);
                $("#avatar_submit").show(1000);
            } else {
                alert('上传失败');
            }
        },
        'onClearQueue' : function(queueItemCount) {
            alert( $('#img1') );
        },
        'onCancel' : function(file) {
            alert('The file ' + file.name + ' was cancelled.');
        }
    });

    //头像裁剪
    var jcrop_api, boundx, boundy;

    function updateCoords(c)
    {
        $('#x').val(c.x);
        $('#y').val(c.y);
        $('#w').val(c.w);
        $('#h').val(c.h);
    };
    function checkCoords()
    {
        if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
        alert('请选择图片上合适的区域');
        return false;
    };
    function updatePreview(c){
        if (parseInt(c.w) > 0){
            var rx = 112 / c.w;
            var ry = 112 / c.h;
            $('#preview').css({
                width: Math.round(rx * boundx) + 'px',
                height: Math.round(ry * boundy) + 'px',
                marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * c.x) + 'px',
                marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * c.y) + 'px'
            });
        }
        {
            var rx = 130 / c.w;
            var ry = 130 / c.h;
            $('#preview2').css({
                width: Math.round(rx * boundx) + 'px',
                height: Math.round(ry * boundy) + 'px',
                marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * c.x) + 'px',
                marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * c.y) + 'px'
            });
        }
        {
            var rx = 200 / c.w;
            var ry = 200 / c.h;
            $('#preview3').css({
                width: Math.round(rx * boundx) + 'px',
                height: Math.round(ry * boundy) + 'px',
                marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * c.x) + 'px',
                marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * c.y) + 'px'
            });
        }
    };

    $("#avatar_submit").click(function(){
        var img = $("#img").val();
        var x = $("#x").val();
        var y = $("#y").val();
        var w = $("#w").val();
        var h = $("#h").val();
        if( checkCoords() ){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "resize.php",
                data: {"img":img,"x":x,"y":y,"w":w,"h":h},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg){
                    if( msg.result_code == 1 ){
                        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('#avatar').offset().top-150},1000,'swing',function(){
                            $('#avatar_msg').show();
                            $('#avatar').attr('src',msg.result_des.small);
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert("失败，傻逼铁道部");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You have to onSelect function on your JCROP; can you set one? You can call updatePreview at the end of the function updateCoords?

Comment: this method is searched from google.  In original php,the code works well, but in codeigniter, it works not properly.